# Azure - "PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'wincache'" after already being loaded

Tags: php, azure, azure-webjobs, wincache

I've got a webjob running on my Azure app service that starts off with the `session_start();` command.

At first - I was getting this error:

> PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'wincache' -
>   session startup failed in
>   D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\myCron\a4ypumbv.4i2\MyCron\myCron.php on
>   line 3

What I ended up doing was going to my App Service -> Application Settings, and I set a custom setting of `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` set to `D:\home\site`, like so:

[image: PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR set to home directory]

Then, inside the `D:\home\site` directory, I uploaded a file titled `phpconfig.ini`, and inside I placed this:

```
extension=D:\home\site\ext\php_wincache.dll
```

I went to https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/wincache-extension and downloaded the appropriate WinCache version - `WinCache 1.3 for PHP 5.6` from SourceForge. After unpacking the `.exe` file, I copied the `php_wincache.dll` file into my `D:\home\site\ext` folder.

Now, when I run the webjob, I get this same error but also another error message right before it saying the `wincache` file was already loaded:

> PHP Warning:  Module 'wincache' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot find save handler 'wincache' -
>   session startup failed in
>   D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\myCron\a4ypumbv.4i2\MyCron\myCron.php on
>   line 3

How can I make these warnings go away completely? Has anyone run into the same problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wincache` has been already installed and enabled in Azure App Service.

In this case, you no longer need to call `session_start()` manually, Azure would start sessions on each page automatically.

Comment: This is for any part of the Azure App Service? Or is this for only App Service webjobs?

Comment: For any part of the Azure App Service.